# How to make datalist the same width as input html

Tags: html, css, input, width, html-datalist

Hi I was wondering how to give a datalist and the corresponding input the same width. I tried the following :

```css
input {
   width: 100%; 
   padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
  datalist,option{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<input list="myList"/>
<datalist id="myList">
 <option> This is a great option</option>
</datalist>
```

The datalist is not the input width when I use the code above. Does anyone know how to make a datalist with the same length as the input he belongs to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Assign a class to each and style with CSS.

CSS

```
.input {
       width: 100%; 
       padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
       border: 1px solid #ddd;
       margin-bottom: 12px;
      }

.Option {
   width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<input list="myList"/>
<datalist id="myList">
 <option class="Option"> This is a great option</option>
</datalist>
```

It might give you the desired outcome.

Comment: There is no element with a class of `.input`.

Comment: Tried it doesn't work unfortunately but your comment is useful sometimes.